# error assignment to expression with array type

Tags: c++, c, pointers, variable-assignment

I have a function named `unpack`, and compiling the C++ code leads to a couple of errors. The code is below:

```
static void unpack(void *v, ekf_t *ekf, int n, int m) {
    /* skip over n, m in data structure */
    char *cptr = (char *) v;
    cptr += 2 * sizeof(int);

    double *dptr = (double *) cptr;
    ekf->x = dptr;
    dptr += n;
    ekf->P = dptr;
    dptr += n * n;
    ekf->Q = dptr;
    dptr += n * n;
    ekf->R = dptr;
    dptr += m * m;
    ekf->G = dptr;
    dptr += n * m;
    ekf->F = dptr;
    dptr += n * n;
    ekf->H = dptr;
    dptr += m * n;
    ekf->Ht = dptr;
    dptr += n * m;
    ekf->Ft = dptr;
    dptr += n * n;
    ekf->Pp = dptr;
    dptr += n * n;
    ekf->fx = dptr;
    dptr += n;
    ekf->hx = dptr;
    dptr += m;
    ekf->tmp0 = dptr;
    dptr += n * n;
    ekf->tmp1 = dptr;
    dptr += n * m;
    ekf->tmp2 = dptr;
    dptr += m * n;
    ekf->tmp3 = dptr;
    dptr += m * m;
    ekf->tmp4 = dptr;
    dptr += m * m;
    ekf->tmp5 = dptr;
}
```

And I get these errors propagated over every line of the code:

```
.../src/ekf.c:203:12: error: assignment to expression with array type
     ekf->x = dptr;
            ^
.../src/ekf.c:205:12: error: assignment to expression with array type
     ekf->P = dptr;
```

It should be noted that the code `unpack` was grabbed from a C library. I have tried using an `extern`, but this does not seem to work too well. Now, when I `make` the original repository (https://github.com/simondlevy/TinyEKF), it seems to compile without a problem. The compile command for TinyEKF, which contains and uses this code, is:

`gcc -Wall -I. -I../../src -o gps_ekf gps_ekf.c ../../src/tiny_ekf.c -lm`

This is found within `/extras/c/` within the repository and certainly uses the `unpack` function.

Comment: Please provide the definition of class/struct ekf_t.

Comment: Just compile it as C, not C++ - you can still link it with your C++ code of course.

Comment: Ensure `x` and `P` type of the fields in `ekf_t` are pointer to double `double *`

Comment: All those members are arrays, and you can't assign to arrays. Pick up a good beginners' book.

Comment: Not a [mcve]...

Comment: It is neither *minimal nor complete*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala With the new context, I understand that the question is not complete. However, at the time of writing this question, I believed that the error was rooted in the way the code was ported from C to C++ and not a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/ericbarch/arduino-libraries/blob/master/TinyEKF/tiny_ekf_struct.h), `ekf.x` is of type `double x[]`. You can't just assign to an array like `ekf->x = dptr;`, as the error says. If you want to copy data from `dptr` to `ekf->x`, you can use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(&ekf->x, dptr, sizeof(ekf->x));
```

The same goes for all the other assignments, most of those fields are `double` arrays.

Comment: Here is what I don't understand. If it works for the examples given in the repository, I am just recreating the entire same thing within my program. Shouldn't it work?

Comment: I believe that they would be arrays in the original code too, being assigned to a double. Which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Which example file is this happening in? It would be interesting to have a look.

Comment: if you look into /extras/c, there is a GPS example that uses this and doesn't spit out an error.

Comment: it compiles, now to check if it functions in the manner that we want it to.